# Receiving SMS in the background in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sms

I'm creating two android applications - 1. Controller-App and 2. Simulator-App, where the Controller-app sends a specific message as an SMS to the Simulator-app, which has to read this message and perform some action.

The problem i faced is, as soon as my emulator receives an SMS, the application is forced to stop.

I want to be able to read the content of the incoming SMS in the background without interrupting my application.

Pls help out!

This is the code for my Main Activity:

```
package com.exampleabc.home;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainAct extends Activity {

IntentFilter intentFilter;

private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView SMSes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        SMSes.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    Button bed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
    Button den = (Button)findViewById(R.id.den);
    Button kit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kitchen);

    Button sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sms);

    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED SCTION");

    sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            sendSMS("5556","hello there!");
        }
    });



    kit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent k=new Intent(MainAct.this,Kitchen.class);
            startActivityForResult(k,0);

        }
    });

    den.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent j=new Intent(MainAct.this,Den.class);
            startActivityForResult(j,0);

        }
    });

    bed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(MainAct.this,Bedroom.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);

        }
    });
}

protected void onResume()
{
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver,intentFilter);
    super.onResume();
}

protected void onPause()
{
    unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

private void sendSMS(String PhnNum, String Messg)
{
    SmsManager sms= SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(PhnNum,null,Messg,null,null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.act_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is the code for my SMSReceiver class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle!=null)
    {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;++i)
        {
            msgs[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str+="SMS from" + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str+=" :";
            str+=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str+="\n";
        }


        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }
}

}
```

And here's my LogCat :

```
06-15 11:44:41.851: W/KeyCharacterMap(465): No keyboard for id 0

06-15 11:44:41.851: W/KeyCharacterMap(465): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

06-15 11:45:06.711: D/AndroidRuntime(465): Shutting down VM

06-15 11:45:06.724: W/dalvikvm(465): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.exampleabc.home.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exampleabc.home.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.exampleabc.home-2.apk]

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exampleabc.home.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.exampleabc.home-2.apk]

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2780)

06-15 11:45:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  ... 10 more
06-15 11:45:10.506: I/Process(465): Sending signal. PID: 465 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from your logcat

Comment: what is your android version? post logcat error too

Comment: @shayan Im using an Android 4.2 emulator